# calculating x and y distances, and not displacement between two places using google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, maps

I need to use google maps api for calculating the x and y distances between the two places, since google maps uses mercator projection. I don't need the distance between the two places, but instead the delta x (along meridians) and delta y (along parallels). If there were two places with coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) with lat-longs (lat1,long1) and (lat2, long2), I want to calculate x2-x1, and y2-y1, the sum of square of these two of course giving the square of displacement between the two places. Can google maps api directly return cartesian coordinates?

Comment: you expressed yourself not acurate, do you want the delta latitude and delta Longitude?  Should the rersult be in degrees?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of methods on `GMSProjection`to convert between coordinates (latitude-longitude) and points.

```
/** Maps an Earth coordinate to a content coordinate. */
- (CGPoint)pointForCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

/** Maps a content coordinate to an Earth coordinate. */
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinateForPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

I don't think the methods to get distances between points are there, but you should be able to use a standard formula. [Here's one](http://blog.digitalagua.com/2008/06/30/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-objective-c/):

```
CGFloat DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(CGPoint point1,CGPoint point2)
{
    CGFloat dx = point2.x - point1.x;
    CGFloat dy = point2.y - point1.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

given two points in WGS84 degrees:

```
(lon1, lat1),
(lon2, lat2)
```

To get the delta Latitude:

```
dLat = lat2- lat1;
```

same for longitide

```
dLon = lon2 - lon1;
```

The delta result is now in degrees.

If you want your result in meters, you must take the projected coordinates in x,y

```
deltaXMeter = x2 - x1;
deltayMeter = y2 - y1;
```

When x and y are cooridnates in a cartesian meter coordinaet system.

Answer (score 0):

try this **haversine formula** for measuring the distance between two coordinates in PHP

```
function haversineGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 6371000)
{
  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

  $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
    cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
  return $angle * $earthRadius;
}
```